Identifier field 'linked_corporate_account_id' named in '@MapsId' does not exist in entity
I migrated Spring Boot 2 to Spring Boot 3. During Boot time I get this error:
Table 1:
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.EnumType;
import jakarta.persistence.Enumerated;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.MapsId;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "corporate_account_linkages")
public class CorporateAccountLinkage {

  @EmbeddedId
  private CorporateAccountLinkageKey corporateAccountLinkageKey;

  @ManyToOne
  @MapsId("corporate_account_id")
  @JoinColumn(name = "corporate_account_id")
  private CorporateAccount corporateAccountId;

  @ManyToOne
  @MapsId("linked_corporate_account_id")
  @JoinColumn(name = "linked_corporate_account_id")
  private CorporateAccount linkedCorporateAccountId;

Table 2:
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Embeddable;

@Embeddable
public class CorporateAccountLinkageKey implements Serializable {
    
  @Column(name = "corporate_account_id", nullable = false)
  private Long corporateAccountId;

  @Column(name = "linked_corporate_account_id", nullable = false)
  private Long linkedCorporateAccountId;

I get error:
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Identifier field 'linked_corporate_account_id' named in '@MapsId' does not exist in entity 'com.platform.entity.CorporateAccountLinkage'
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: component: com.platform.entity.orporateAccountLinkageKey property not found: linked_corporate_account_id
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Component.getProperty(Component.java:506) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.AnnotatedJoinColumns.resolveMapsId(AnnotatedJoinColumns.java:222) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]

What are the possible options to migrate this code for latest Spring Boot?
Should I replace @MapsId with something else or add @MapsId into table CorporateAccountLinkageKey? Or there is some other solution?

@MapsId needs to reference the field in the entity not the column name in the database. So @MapsId("corporateAccountId"). Which is also what the exception is, quite clearly imho, telling you.

Thanks this is fixing the issue. Any idea why previous Spring Boot version old column name was working fine?

It wasn't working fine, it was just ignored and the @JoinColumn kicked in. This has also nothing to do with Spring Boot but the version of Hibernate in use. With the proper @MapsId I now believe you can also remove the @JoinColumn as that information is inferred from the field that is being mapped.
